# How to allow Requirement Version Link Management for executed test cases on Testlink

Tags: testlink

I'm trying to link an executed test case in TestLink to a requirement, but I'm getting this message

> system config blocks requirement version link management for executed test case versions

Any idea what should be changed in the configuration file to allow requirement version link management for executed test case versions?

Comment: I agree with the default setting of the testlink. Once you took the answer, testlink will allow people to edit the requirement while we already have test result. A test result can only cover a fixed requirement version. If we change the requirement, the result can be unreasonable.

Comment: Normally, the only reason to design a test is to cover a requirement, so I assume the test execution should start after the link between test and requirement is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer to my question,

all needed is to change the following in config.inc.php

```
$tlCfg->testcase_cfg->reqLinkingDisabledAfterExec = True;

$tlCfg->testcase_cfg->freezeReqVersionAfterExec = True;
```

To:

```
$tlCfg->testcase_cfg->reqLinkingDisabledAfterExec = FALSE;

$tlCfg->testcase_cfg->freezeReqVersionAfterExec = FALSE;
```

Comment: I had to also change some more properties `$tlCfg->reqTCLinks->freezeLinkOnNewTCVersion = FALSE;` and `$tlCfg->reqTCLinks->freezeLinkOnNewREQVersion = FALSE;`